# Build Ubuntu Desktop using ubuntu-meta

Tags: server, desktop-environments, vagrant

Objective: Fresh install of updated desktop every week
Assumptions: Applying the [ubuntu-meta](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/ubuntu-desktop) to [ubuntu server](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/cosmic64) will get me a desktop environment
Assumptions: I can apply the tar.gz or dsc file instead of installing each package listed individually

QUESTION: How do I apply the ubuntu-meta package to ubuntu server?

note: i understand i'll have extra server related stuff but i'm not too worried about that. Beats having to roll my own base box and keep it updated.

Comment: This seems like a tremendous amount of unnecessary work merely to do what Ubuntu already does automatically for you...upgrading packages. And it probably won't do what you expect. But if that's really what you want to try, then the command you are looking for is `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. Experimenting with it won't hurt anything. Using it as an update strategy, however, is unwise. Better alternatives are available.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the comment. Might make a bit more sense if you put more emphasis on fresh install rather than updated desktop. I would much prefer pulling down an official desktop version from vagrant but that's not something that's offered.